# What type of security measure/contingent conditions could make jumping into a portal impossible inside a laboratory?

Tags: physics, wormholes, vacuum, portal

I am writing a spy-adjacent story where one of the characters is able to open and close portals that teleport them to a set number of known locations.

There is a moment in which this character tries to escape an applied physics laboratory complex by opening a portal, but, for some reason, is unable to do so. Possibly because of an unexpected safety measure, or because of the particular conditions inside it.

I have no idea about physics, but I've looked into vacuum things like the vacuum catastrophe. If there is any way that opening a portal in that particular setting could cause a condition that would result in fatality (so that the character **has to** get out in a different way), I would love to know. I'm not even asking about specific safety measures *per se*, but for a circumstance that would make their usual escape route impossible to use. It doesn't need to be vacuum-related, that was just the first idea that crossed my mind.

Comment: being an applied physics lab, it's surely full of weird physicsy stuff that can interfere with portals - take your pick. Maybe the portals don't work near particle colliders, electron microscopes, high voltages, strong magnets, X-rays, unobtainium crystals, blah blah blah...

Comment: Could you be a lot more specific, please? First, what difference do you see between 'security measures' and 'contingent conditions'?

How can it matter whether the target room is merely a room like any other, or is inside a laboratory or a classroom, an office or a lecture theatre?

Comment: There are dozens of possiblities. A more important question is what would best advance your plotline. A security measure that needs to be circumvented, a natural circumstance that needs to be corrected or waited out, a misunderstanding of the portal tech, a communications glitch? I came up with eight possibilities, and this site is a bad choice for infinite lists.

Comment: This reminds me of Agents of SHIELD's villain Gordon, an Inhuman capable of opening portals to anywhere in the world. However he was unable to leave a certain place that way if he was inside a "Quantum Field Disruptor".

Comment: Is this supposed to be anything more relevant than technobabble?  Spelling out "tries to escape but is unable to do so" is usually good enough for the reader if it's woven into dialog.  e.g. _"We can't escape that way because [technobabble]!  We could be killed!  We'll have to get out a different way!"_  -- I suggest this word salad:  _the portal's quantum flux field distortion is causing an entanglement feedback anomaly!_

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Faraday cage

Your microwave oven has one, to prevent the radiation getting out.  If you put your cell phone in one and try to dial it, it can't be reached.

You can, if you wish, make it feel like they hit a wall.

Comment: And the lab is covered with one to prevent wireless communication to the outside world, preventing surveilance devices.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu Protection of lab equipment is another possibility

Comment: Yea, definitely. If there are very sensitive equipment, a faraday cage will help reduce noise.

Answer (score 15):

**Frame Challenge**

Why make it a Physics problem? In order to open a Portal from *current location* to *known locations*, the Protagonist has to know where they are. Not down to an exact GPS co-ordinate, but in order to map the Portal between the two locations, they need to be aware of their location.

If they were captured, sedated or otherwise smuggled into the Lab in such a way that they have no idea about their current location, then they lack the critical bit of information they would need to open a Portal.

It's a lot easier story-wise, you don't have to come up with some convoluted half-baked physics excuse and there are other implications that you as a writer can have fun with this rule.

Comment: Gully Foyle is my name / And Terra is my nation. / Deep space is my dwelling place, / The stars my destination.

Comment: Context for the above comment: The novel 'Stars my destination' by Alfred Bester. In it, teleportation is a learnable skill requiring the accurate visualization of both destination and departure point. Anything else poofs you out of existence. This results in the heavy use of labyrinths and secrecy to keep people in and out of places.

Comment: This would be a great idea but, sadly, they must know where they are at the moment. Otherwise they couldn't have snuck in by themselves :(

Comment: @Elsie: Unless, perhaps, the interior is so convoluted (such a lab-yrinthe) and they got turned around so many times, that while they know they're in the "lab", it's way too vague for portaling out.

Answer (score 14):

## Air pressure

(As I reread your post after writing this, I only now realize this is probably what you meant by "vacuum related".)

If you were to open a portal from one location to another with slightly lower air pressure, the air would naturally start flowing into the portal to even out the difference in pressure, creating wind. The bigger the pressure difference, the stronger (and more explosive) the wind would be.

Assuming that the character is being held in this laboratory against their will and their captors have intentionally taken steps to prevent their escape, one way may be to alter the air pressure in the holding cell and informing the character of this. Opening a portal to the outside world from this environment could result in explosive decompression, which would be very dangerous, potentially lethal.

Thus, the captors cannot *prevent* a portal from being opened, but can still take steps to ensure that their prisoner wouldn't be willing to *take the risk* of opening a portal. (As an addendum, the captors *may not even be telling the truth*.)

Comment: Best answer so far. Going from 9 atm to 1 can vaporize the blood within your veins.

Comment: It's my best option so far, I think! I wanted the conditions to stop them from running away to be more "accidental"; this character has snuck into the lab in order to gather some intel and, suddenly, they have to get away as fast as possible. Stopping them from using their TP system works wonders for adding tension to the moment. Now I have to wonder what non-premeditated conditions could add air pressure to that particular enclosement

Comment: @Elsie the place can be a submarine. It was by the surface when teleporter got in, but submerged to a great depth at some point.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw Submarines have an internal air pressure of about 1 atm, the whole point is that the internal pressure does *not* meaningfully increase during a dive. I don't see how this could work "accidentally", you won't tend to see a differential greater than a few tenths of an atmosphere, which will make a stiff breeze at best. You'd need the whole facility ready to blow like a pressure cooker.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie you're right. Maybe a diving chamber then? Those are supposed to bring you up to pressure in great depths.

Answer (score 8):

Opening a wormhole portal is not possible with science as we know it here and now. So you need some science-fictional "McGuffin" to do that, and you are free to introduce restrictions on it. Just consider where else these restrictions appear, to make things consistent.

- This particular physics lab has magnetic fields which interfere with the McGuffin. Can portals be opened in electric cars?
- It has a strobe light effect or a sound effect which prevents the concentration to open the portal. Does the character have problems with [flash photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosensitive_epilepsy)?

Comment: Actually, yes, the character is highly photosensitive. I would love to know more about both your ideas, I'm going to google things further!

Answer (score 6):

### A certain amount of kinetic energy is required

This is a real phenomenon that might exist for a subset of [thin shell spherically symmetric wormholes](https://www.galacticlibrary.net/wiki/Wormholes#Spherically_symmetric_wormholes).
Consider the diagram (source from link):

[image: diagram]

An object passing through a thin shell wormhole experiences a sudden jump in spatial curvature (rightward curvature immediately becomes leftward, or vice versa), causing mechanical stress to be applied to any object attempting to pass through. Energy is required to overcome this force, and the upshot is than an object requires a minimum amount of kinetic energy to pass through. Too slow, and it just "bounces off".

Comment: This is very interesting, but I'm sorry if I didn't understand correctly, how could I apply this to a laboratory setting? It has to be a special occasion where the portals cannot be used, because otherwise, the rest of the time those portals do always work. How could I make it so that the place where they are is why this happens, while it doesn't happen anywhere else?

Comment: @Elsie I think the misunderstanding's mine. I read your Q and wrote my A in the few minutes I had for work break. There's a couple of options that could be explored. Firstly, maybe the character who attempts it is simply unaware of the minimum kinetic energy requirement, and after after a couple "low-speed" attempts gives up and searches for another way out.

Comment: Another option (probably the better option) is that the wormhole was made too small. The amount of push-back depends on the amount of curvature relative to the object that attempts passage. You might get through larger wormholes at walking pace, but smaller ones need a good running start to attain the minimum KE. "Too small" and perhaps a human physically can't build up enough KE under their own power to get through.

Comment: @BMF hmmm... It's a physics lab, and this guy can make portals, so there are clear advancements in GR. Maybe the walls of the lab are built of a special material that prevents spacetime warping, meaning the teleporter can't just punch through the walls like they usually can, forcing them to only make portals that are too small for them to traverse safely (much less comfortably) unless they can find a room or hallway big enough

Comment: "a real phenomenon"?

Comment: @RadovanGarabík "... that might exist..."

Answer (score 5):

## Make portals give off sparks

Since portals slice atoms in half, they cause fission of local materials, which tends to cause sparks and heat generation. The labs have some sort of knockout gas to disable intruders which is flammable, so when they try to make a portal it causes an explosion which could kill them.

Answer (score 4):

Although I like the already posted Faraday cage solution the most, if you need something active, something that can later be disabled or deactivated, then just use a **strong electromagnetic interference**.

Is the portal magical? There is a common trope of magic and technology, especially electronics, jamming each other.

Is the portal technological? Then it needs some way to communicate with the other side. A strong electromagnetic interference could jam that communication.

Just have a magnetron, a particle accelerator, an MRI machine, or anything which gives off a strong magnetic or electromagnetic field, or does it at the exact frequency which would jam or interfere with your portal. If your lab studies high-energy physics instead of being a classroom for classical mechanics, then you'd bound to find some kind of a machine which generates the required interference not commonly found in other locations.

Answer (score 3):

## Establish requirements, then break them

One way to limit a character's ability to open portal is to establish some kind of requirement from the character's point of view for portals to be opened, then figure out a scenario where that requirement isn't met.

Looking at portals in other media, the game Portal only allows portals to be opened in specific locations (in this case, only along walls that have been coated with material from *[spoiler for a 12 year old game]*.) Portals in the Doctor Strange movies are opened using a Sling Ring, a magical item which if lost or stolen prevents Strange from easily escaping.

Are there rules for *where* these portals can be opened? ("I can only create portals on biological materials like wood, but this is all concrete!")

Or perhaps the portals are kind of large and needs enough empty space to open? ("Why are all the rooms and corridors so small and have such low ceilings? Where am I supposed to open a portal?")

Are the portals created using some kind of device that can fail? ("I forgot to recharge my portal gun!", "Oh no, I dropped the portalizer gem down the well!")

Or if it's a supernatural ability of the character, perhaps they still need something to open them? ("I open portals by spinning a pencil between my fingers and re-projecting its rotation onto space itself until a hole forms. But oh dear, I dropped my pencil somewhere and I can't find something else of the right shape, size and weight that I'm used to.")

If this is a supernatural ability, then the character's state of mind could be key. Does opening a portal require a calm mind? Or intense focus? Have something happen that makes them start panicking and become unable to control their emotions, or have them get poisoned by something at the lab which makes them unable to focus clearly.

Does the character need to stand still for several seconds to open up a portal in front of them? ("Tearing space apart with their bare hands"?) Have them chased by guards, forcing them to keep running.

Are the portals opened by making complex magical arm movements? Have them fall and break their arm.

Finding some, explicit or implicit, required conditions to open portals seems like the best way to build in a weakness that can be exploited for story reasons. Preferably one where the reader doesn't immediately think "oh yeah, that's going to go wrong later" when it's first set up.

Answer (score 2):

When people think of physics labs, they often picture lasers, antimatter containment and miniature particle accelerators.

When I think of physics labs, I think of high school physics and how my family of laws of physics (I am the Square Cube Law) can be unusually cruel.

I am supposing your character portals are static relative to Earth. All you need to trap them is to keep them from reaching the portal opening.

A simple experiment on rectilinear motion and my cousins Newton's First and Second Laws will do. Have them stand on a 10m wide treadmill. Atop the contraption are suspended walls so that the teleporter can't walk out of the experiment. Now when they open the portal, start the treadmill. Just make it move to match the exact same speed as the person is walking or running, so that their speed relative to the portal is zero. Troll them by varying the speed here and there in either way. Record it and upload to SecondPersonPipe with the title "Teleport FAIL!" for profit, preferably with altered frame rate and with Benny Hill as background music.

Answer (score 2):

How about good(?), old, very much non-physics coercion?

> "*That's a nice portal you've got there. Feel free to use it. But if you do, you'll never know what happened to your beloved, whom right now I seem to be pointing a vaporizer at. Muahahaha!"*

Answer (score 1):

The portals created by the MC are set to close automatically after a set amount of material (a bit over the MC's mass plus a safety margin) passes through them in order to avoid having to close each of them every time manually and to deter any pursuers. Unfortunately, the portals also give off a lot of infrared radiation or smoke-like particles, which the lab's systems detect as signs of fire and activate the fire suppression system. As a consequence, immediately after opening a portal, the room gets filled with water, carbon dioxide, halon or other fire suppressants, which flood through the portal, resulting in the previously mentioned automatic closure.

Answer (score 1):

In the *[Long Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Earth_(series))* and *[Merchant Princes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merchant_Princes)* series, humans can "jump" from world to world. However, those jumps can only take place at the same altitude. One can build "escape proof" prisons (or other types of secure facilities) by ensuring that the containment room is underground and equivalent volumes in adjacent worlds are filled in with dirt/debris.

Perhaps in your world, portal jumps that change altitude also change kinetic energy. These changes result in changes in temperature of the person jumping. Small changes in brain temperature are sufficient to cause unconsciousness and brain damage. "Secure facilities" are buried underground at a sufficient depth that causes fatal brain damage to people trying to leap in/out. All secure labs look like missile silos with a labyrinth to travel between levels, so that even if the kinetic energy issue from conservation of momentum (remember, the plane spins), then the exact location of the underground lab is hidden within [a maze of twisty little passages, all alike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure).

Answer (score 1):

The portal is inside a number of shell like spheres, which are rotating very fast. The centrifugal force, which the researchers are subject to equals to a g- always away from the portal. Anything coming out of the portal, is weightless subjectively (the whole affair is in space) and just drifts around the portal, with the researchers and defenses circling extremely fast below.

Horror Addition: The chamberfloor has exendable blades that slice any intruder into carpacio.

Answer (score 0):

How about the lab is filled with recording equipment, knowing this our hero does not want to use his ability to give away how it works. He can teleport out but at the cost of given his captor ability to learn how to use, how to block or worse yet, how to track his ability.

Answer (score 0):

The laboratory is researching the same type of portals the character uses, and unbeknownst to the character until now, opening an entrance portal near a stronger network to a separate portal network isn't possible; it's either force your way into their network (and if that's possible, it's probably noticeable, and may limit you to using their exits), or wait until their network goes offline, or find some other way out.